# List shows 4 items in debugger even if filled with exactly one element

Tags: c#, list, linq, distinct

When I look at list populated with single item in debugger its `_items` field contains 4 elements. Can you explain the behavior?

I've found that while debugging my console application to learn about `Distinct` and `ToList` and result confuses me. Code:

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>() { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 };
List<int> distinctNums = nums.Distinct().ToList();
int[] distinctNums2 = nums.Distinct().ToArray();
```

- `distinctNums`  has 4 elements in `_items` : `(6, 0, 0, 0)` which is clearly wrong.
- `distinctNums2` has 1 item `(6)` which is correct.

Comment: Both are returning a single element in the list, How are you checking the result ?

Comment: I've significantly updated your post to reflect debugger's involvement. Feel free to edit if you don't like it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will create the list `distinctNums` that contains only one item, just as you should expect. However, lists in .NET are backed by an array which is automatically resized as you add items to it. This array starts off with a size of 4, so the internal array would be `[4, 0, 0, 0]` if you happen to probe it via reflection or in a debugger.

But if you check, you would find `distinctNums.Count == 1`. Compare [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties.

Comment: looks like the OP used `Capacity` to check the number of items? So terrible.

Comment: +1 @KingKing - more likely OP simply clicked "+" till see first actual field (try looking at a list in VS editor while debugging and click "Raw view")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, I've just tried it, and it's the internal array `_items`. Right at the first, he should have seen that the public member was shown as only 1 item `[0]` with value `6`.

Comment: As @Alexei Levenkov  said I was just looking at the raw data when investigating a problem and it threw me. Thought it was causing my bug but turned out it wasn't.

Answer (score 3):

Both `distinctNums` and `distinctNums2` really just contain one object.

The list with four items that you're seeing in the debugger is only the array that backs the `List<int>`. You can see that its `Count` is `1` and that if you iterate the list, it only returns a single `6`.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` is an abstraction on top of `T[]` (a standard array). The size of the array doesn't matter. When you allocate a `List<T>` with one item the compiler does not allocate `new T[1]`, it gives you some room to grow (it has to reallocate a new array and copy items over when you outgrow the original one which is a relatively expensive operation). `Count` gives you the lists length and if you call it on that list you will get 1. The other three indexes have the default value of zero and are not part of your list, they're part of the underlying array. They're not relevant. If you tried to do `myList[3]` you would still get an exception, it wouldn't just return that 0.

To bring this back to the original question, in both cases `Distinct` returns and `IEnumerable<int>` with one item. When you call `ToList` it allocates a new list, the count is 1, it's underlying data structure is an `int[]` with a starting length of 4. If you added more items it would grow. In the second example you call `ToArray` so it allocated a new `int[1]` and returns the reference to it.